# Convert most syntax for points into "x,y"

Tags: regex, haxe

I'm working on a Haxe project that will, when finished, allow users to code in Haxe by typing in plain English. Example input:

```
Create a number called "Foo".
Set Foo to 100.
Print Foo to the console.
```

Right now, I'm trying to use an EReg (also known as RegExp or Regex) object to convert most of the common point syntaxes into `x,y`, which is something the main conversion function can easily understand. Here's all of the syntax features I'd like to take into consideration, in some combination or another:

```
100,200
100, 200
(100,200)
[100, 200]
x:100,y:200
(X:100, Y:200)
[ X: 100, y: 200 ]
```

Each of these strings `a` should be evaluated by a Regex object `r` with `r.replace(a, "$1,$2")` to get `100,200`. Basically, this includes:

- Any amount of whitespace
- An optional pair of brackets or parentheses
- An optional upper- or lower-case `x:` and `y:`
- But always two numbers separated by a comma.

I've gotten each of these features correct with some Regex or another, and I had everything except the "x:"/"y:" in the same one. But because I don't have much experience with Regex, I can't figure out how to evaluate all of these conditions at the same time. Is this possible within the bounds of Regex, and if so, how could I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "two numbers separated by a comma."  That can be made using `/.*?(\d+).*,.*?(\d+).*/`.  Can X and Y ever be reversed? (e.g. `[y:100,x:100]`).  Note that I'm using javascript regex. Not sure if it's different in haxe.

Comment: I hadn't thought of reversing X and Y! That would be a very good option to include. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
[\(\[]? *([xX]: *)?(\d+), *(?:[yY]: *)?(\d+) *[\)\]]?
```

But I guess that it's not necessery to match the whole pattern. Just try to match digits, like:

```
(\d+), *(?:[yY]: *)?(\d+)
```

Comment: Thanks for the super-fast reply! If I were to use your second suggestion, it would not remove the brackets/parentheses as I need it to. However, the first one works perfectly, after I replaced `$1,$2` with `$2,$4`.